# Facebook Javascript SDK using 'me' to call the graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently making a Facebook app using the Javascript SDK. All examples online show 'me' being used to access the user information. For Example:

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"photos{likes,name}"}
```

If I continue to use this, will this access any user that is currently logged in or does this need to be replaced by a userId after log in?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never need to replace this with an ID, in fact you should always use `/me` instead of `/user-id`. It will always get the data of the currently authorized user (depending on the User Access Token you use for the API call).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much :)